# Onomatopoeia for the sound of something coming to a complete halt or fitting right in

Tags: translation, onomatopoeia

There is a Japanese onomatopoeia "pita(ピタッ)" indicating something coming to a complete halt or fitting right in. What is an English equivalaent for this onomatopoeia? A few websites specialized in Japanese-English comic sound effects have it as "stop" or "halt". Does it sound natural/reasonable to native English speakers?

Comment: Whatever it is *clunks* into place.

Comment: There are probably a lot of manga conventions and we probably don't know much about them on here, so possibly best to ask on a manga site... but movement sounds tend to incorporate some kind of shhhh as in whoosh or shwiiing. I don't think it's a coincidence that these words both feature a w sound, but for an object moving and then dropping right into place / coming to a sudden halt I would go for something like shhhhhhtup or shhhhhhtok.

Comment: There's also a kind of wzzzjd sound that would be understood as a sound effect but is problematic to write because of the weirdness of English spelling. Somehow this one makes the movement sound more planned - probably the zzzj is an engine on some level.

Comment: Also kerplunk, adverb.

Comment: Consider "click."  Sort of sounds like the noise an object makes when it clicks into place.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Seems like so many ways to express it！  Sato

Comment: @TerukoSato None of these replies is giving you what you are asking.

Comment: @rchivers "wzzzjd" I have no idea what this could mean.

Comment: I suggest Click works well, especially in the graphic format you describe.  Picture a slot machine, where each of the winning numbers - 7 - settles into place as you win the big prize.. Click, click, and click - and then alarms and sirens as coins gush from the machine!

Comment: “Snick” might be used for indicating “fitting right in” with precision.  *the snick of a key in a lock*